# R shiny selectizeInput autocomplete

Tags: r, autocomplete, shiny

I am programming a shiny app and want to use selectizeInput. Unfortunately, the number of choices is huge (>250,000), causing the app breaking down on launching. So, I am interested if there is a possibility to solve this problem.
One way I thought of is something like autocomplete à la Google search. Is there a widget or anything like that to solve my problem? What I do not want to use is a "pre-filter" if possible...
Thx a lot!!

Comment: selectize.js  does support `Remote Source` have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223774/selectize-js-and-shiny-select-choices-from-a-remote-api

Comment: @FlorianKellner could you please share how you implemented the solution server side? I have exactly your identical problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you limit the number of options with the option `maxOptions`, does this solve the issue ?

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput("variable", "Variable:",
                   c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                     "Transmission" = "am",
                     "Gears" = "gear"), 
                   options=list(maxOptions=2)
    ),
    tableOutput("data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderTable({
      mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi Stéphane! Limiting the number of options did not work as I want to access all of the objects. However, I found a solution to my problem: there is the possibility to populate the selectizeInput from server-side. Thus, the box does not "explode" with entries when loading the ui. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello @Flo. Limiting the number of options does not prevent the access to all the options: they are available by autocompletion. But you have found your solution, nice.

Comment: @FlorianKellner could you please share how you implemented the solution server side? I have exactly your identical problem!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem: there is the possibility to populate the selectizeInput from server-side. Thus, the box does not "explode" with entries when loading the ui.
--> shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html